# Securing a ConnectionString

Tags: c#, mysql, security

i want to secure a connectionstring so it is not possible to "read" it out for any purpose.

at the moment i'm doing it like this and i know it is like the Windows Firewall, open in all directions...

```
private static string connStr = "server=localhost;user=MySuperSecretUser;database=MySuperSecretDatabase;port=3306;password=MySuperSecretPassword;sslMode=none;";
private static MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
private static MySqlConnection conn2 = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
```

does anybody know how i can secure it so nobody is able to help me out here?

Comment: _not possible to "read" it out for any purpose_ - then you might as well delete it.

Comment: I know it can be done using _Encrypt Configuration Files_. Here is some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files#encrypting-configuration-file-sections-using-protected-configuration) about that

Comment: *want to secure a connectionstring so it is not possible to "read" it out for any purpose.* this is... wait, what the connection string for then? though if its on [web.config you can encrypt it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx)..

Comment: Here's hoping this is for a web API/server application and not an application released to end users.

Comment: @ChristianMurschall That encryption can be reversed either with RSA being used or DPAPI as long as the decryption is run under the same machine and user (would have access to the same key storage used to encrypt it).

Comment: A good way to protect data in the connection string is not writting secret data in it. I would suggest using windows authentication instead user/password.

Comment: Well, it is supposed to be used on the Client's, not on the Server...

Comment: "it is supposed to be used on the Client" means the question is very incomplete. Note that encryption is easy. Where to store the key is the hard part.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using standard .Net. Follow below steps for encrypting the Connection String

#### Encrypting Web.Config

**Step 1**
Open Command Prompt with Administrator privileges

**Step 2**
At the Command Prompt, enter below command

> cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

Step 3:

In case your web Config is located in "D:\Articles\EncryptWebConfig" directory path, then enter the following to encrypt the ConnectionString. Please note that ConnectionString is **case sensitive**

> ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "connectionStrings" "D:\Articles\EncryptWebConfig"

#### Accessing Decrypted Configuration Settings

ASP.NET automatically decrypts the contents of the Web.Config file when it processes the file. Therefore, no additional steps are required to decrypt the encrypted configuration settings.

> string ConnString =
> ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt it, but if your code can use it, someone with access to the code can also decrypt it.

The solution I've seen is for the developers to restrict access to the code, and for the server admin team to restrict access to the config files.

The server admin team (who already know this information) use the encryption tool to set up the config file on the web server. The programmers can't access the config file and any hacker that reads the config file can't decrypt it.

Comment: Any hacker with access to the right account _can_ decrypt it. Hint: how does the app use the connectionstring?